# Wifi on BCM4364 using brcmfac driver and firmware

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

Where can I get the BCM4364 brcmfac driver for Ubuntu 20.04?

"Firmware"="C-4364__s-B2/maui.trx",
"TxCap"="C-4364__s-B2/maui-X0.txcb",
"Regulatory"="C-4364__s-B2/maui-X0.clmb",
"NVRAM"="C-4364__s-B2/P-maui-X0_M-HRPN_V-u__m-7.5.txt"})

I tried `wget https://packages.aunali1.com/apple/wifi-fw/18G2022/C-4364__s-B2/kauai.trx`, but I got `temporary failure in name resolution`. Is this site still up?

Out of desperation, I tried using the MacOS BCM4364 driver on Ubuntu, but of course it didn't work. I'm getting `Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4364-pcie... failed with error -2` .

This is what `dmesg | grep brcmfmac` shows immediately after a reboot:

```
[    4.690795] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    4.691278] brcmfmac 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.801656] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac4364-pcie for chip BCM4364/3
[    4.803604] brcmfmac 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4364-pcie.Apple Inc.-MacBookPro15,2.txt failed with error -2
[    4.803616] brcmfmac 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4364-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[    5.129065] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac4364-pcie for chip BCM4364/3
[    5.161189] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4364/3 wl0: Jun 24 2018 21:15:25 version 9.130.28.44.32.1.55 FWID 01-d4b01473
```

I'm seeing a thread from last year on the exact same issue but there is no resolution:
[How can I activate wifi on BCM4364 using brcmfac driver & firmware?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260088/how-can-i-activate-wifi-on-bcm4364-using-brcmfac-driver-firmware)
Anyone on that thread happen to figure this out?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I activate wifi on BCM4364 using brcmfac driver & firmware?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260088/how-can-i-activate-wifi-on-bcm4364-using-brcmfac-driver-firmware)