# Wifi driver for MAcbook on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, macbook

I followed [this guide](https://wiki.t2linux.org/guides/wifi-bluetooth/) to install Bluetooth and WiFi drivers. From the guide I ran downloaded the firmware file on my Mac, ran the script there, then booted into Ubuntu and ran the script there as well, however I was not able to get wireless connection after running all of the commands and following the steps. I ran `sudo journalctl -k --grep=brcmfmac` and this was the output I got.

[image]

My brcm/ folder looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the elements of the solution you've tried in the post itself rather than relying on a link to the guide you followed. We need to understand what steps you took specifically and the error messages you got in the process as they will help us better diagnose your problem. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Please also avoid screenshots, copy the text from the terminal, that way it will get indexed and more people will find your post with google and ... you might get more upvotes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I activate wifi on BCM4364 using brcmfac driver & firmware?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260088/how-can-i-activate-wifi-on-bcm4364-using-brcmfac-driver-firmware)

Comment: No. When running wget https://packages.aunali1.com/apple/wifi-fw/18G2022/C-4364__s-B2/kauai.trx it is unable to resolve host address ‘packages.aunali1.com’. Is there another way to obtain these files?